# Transparent navbar to visible when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I saw an transparent theme navbar that have really nice effect when scrolling down.

Here is what happends when scrolling down.

1. It goes from 0 opacity to 100
2. Navbar fixed containers height becomes less.
3. Color:#fff; becomes color:000;

[Here is direct link to demo page of that theme](http://www.awerest.com/demo/myway/light/)

Guessing it is javascript/jquery that is used there and i know only HTML & CSS.
Could anyone help me make it similar like in that theme?

Comment: It's good that you linked to an example, but you should also research various approaches, try one, and then ask about a specific problem you have while implementing it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack overflow. Generally here you'll get more help if you have a go at writing the code yourself, then ask for help when you get stuck on a particular problem. So... have a go at it yourself, then if you get stuck, edit your question and add the code you have so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I'm gonna throw you a bone here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDLp2/2/):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('.navbar').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 500));
});
```

Magic number alert: 500 is the divider for the scrollTop, the lower the number the faster the opacity goes above 1 (opacity should be between 0 and 1.

So what this code does is listen to scrolling on the document and set the opacity of the navbar according to the scroll position.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you mate! :)
All i needed was a push in the right direction.